# Firebase signInWithPopup wrong url - provider is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue with my Google SignInWithPopup.

On my local dev environment, signing up with google opens a pop up with a URL that starts with :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myId.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FmyProjectId.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fhandler&state=
```

On my production env (a different firebase project), signing up with google opens a pop up with a URL that starts with :

```
https://myProjectId.firebaseapp.com,/__/auth/handler?apiKey=myProdAPIKey%2C&appName=[DEFAULT]&authType=signInViaPopup&providerId=google.com&scopes=profile&eventId=xxxxxxxx&v=7.20.0
```

Everything works as expected in my dev env. Not in my production env.

In the first case, the following returns the expected provider object :

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

In the 2nd case, provider is `undefined`. What am I missing here ?

I import firebase as follows :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying importing the package as

```
import firebase from 'firebase/auth'
```